# Insane battery drain compared to Windows

Tags: battery

I have a Lenovo Y720 laptop. On Windows I get up to 5 hours battery life, while on Linux I get 1 hour maximum. Fresh install, nothing installed, brightness half way down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the battery backup in Windows is better than Linux. I have seen that Linux maintains my CPU around its base clock of 2.2GHz even when idle, whereas Windows down clocks to less than 1GHz. This maybe a reason.

Also your laptop seems to come with a Nvidia GTX 10 series graphic card. This card might be enabled all the time and using the proprietory driver. Try changing it to the open-source driver using 'Additional drivers' tab of 'Software & Updates' settings.

You can check out Bumblebee project, which aims to enable GPU switching in  systems with Hybrid graphics for better battery life. This will switch the GPU under use according to the work load. This is enabled by default in Windows.
https://bumblebee-project.org/
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee